# php_imagick error, Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to load module

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to get php_imagick extension to work in windows 8.1 x64.

I have *Apache 2.4.12 x86* from Apachelounge, *php 5.6.5*, *ImageMagick-6.9.0-6-Q16-x86*, and downloaded the *php_imagick-3.2.0b2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86* from pecl server.

Everything seems fine. I have imagick listed in phpinfo() along with 179 supported formats.

But whenever I try to open an image with Imagick I get an error like:

> *Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to load
>   module `D:_Server\ImageMagick\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_png_.dll': The
>   specified procedure could not be found*

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like installing an older version of ImageMagick would solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution I found for this was running my IDE as administrator. I'm also using Windows 8.1 x64 and doing this resolved the issue and did not require having to install an older version. My IDE is Visual Studio.